# What is the meaning of Lumen Gentium's "subsistit in" according to the Acta Synodalia of Vatican Council II?

Tags: catholicism, vatican-ii

In [*Lumen Gentium* 8](http://www.vatican.va/archive/hist_councils/ii_vatican_council/documents/vat-ii_const_19641121_lumen-gentium_lt.html) we find the words, "*Haec Ecclesia [...] **subsistit in** Ecclesia catholica...*" ("This Church [...] subsists in the Catholic Church").

The *Acta Synodalia Sacrosancti Concilii Oecumenici Vaticani II* is a collection of all of the speeches, debates, and written submissions of the Council Fathers at Vatican II.  For example, it is well known that "*subsistit in*" replaced the original formulation of "*est*" due to an intervention during the Council.

### Question:

---

According to the *Acta Synodalia* of Vatican II, what is the meaning of "*subsistit in*"?  What did the Council Fathers mean by *subsistit in* and why did they use this term to convey the relation between the Church of Christ and the Catholic Church?

---

**Note: I am only interested in the interpretation of *subsistit in* with respect to the *Acta Synodalia*.**  Strong answers will include insight into central discussions and debates that took place at the Council as well as the names of the parties who put forward various positions.

Comment: If I write an answer summarizing the debates in this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsistit_in) + more quotes from the referenced 2006 paper [A Response to Karl Becker, S.J. On the Meaning of *Subsistit In*](http://cdn.theologicalstudies.net/67/67.2/67.2.7.pdf) + more quotes from the referenced [Card. Ratzinger 2000 interview](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/view.cfm?recnum=3316) which includes  the meaning of "subsistit in" in Dominus Iesu 16 which in turn references Lumen Gentium 8,  would that suffice, or do I need to research more?

Comment: Another resource I will potentially use is the *America* magazine 2000 article [The Impact of Dominus Iesus on Ecumenism](https://www.americamagazine.org/issue/386/article/impact-dominus-iesus-ecumenism) by the same author of the 2006 paper, Francis A. Sullivan, SJ, which is a commentary on "subsistit in" and the famous footnote 56.

Comment: A more recent paper by (Lawrence J. Welch and Guy Mansini OSB) which refute Francis A. Sullivan's position: [*Lumen Gentium* No. 8 and *Subsistit in*, Again](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43251332#?seq=1) which I would include in my answer.  Also often cited is [CDF response to Leonard Boff's book](https://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/cfaith/documents/rc_con_cfaith_doc_19850311_notif-boff_en.html) and [*Unitatis Redintegratio* no. 4](https://www.vatican.va/archive/hist_councils/ii_vatican_council/documents/vat-ii_decree_19641121_unitatis-redintegratio_en.html)

Comment: @GratefulDisciple I suppose if no answer derived from the *Acta* is possible then secondary answers would be acceptable.  Yet even then I would prefer that such secondary answers take as their starting point(s) bishops and theologians who were present at the Council.  People like Ratzinger and Sullivan would therefore be good sources.  If your journal articles rely heavily on the *Acta*, all the better.

Comment: In other words, the clarification should only be made by other documents included in the 4 volumes *Acta* to throw light not only the change of formulation from the original (done by Sebastian Tromp, SJ) but what the bishops and theologians would have understood "subsistit in"?  So similar to how Biblical exegesis in Biblical Theology should only use other NT books or the NT authors to clarify the meaning of a passage?  I understand this would rule out *Dominus Iesu*, CDF response to Leonard Boff's book and Card. Ratzinger interview.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple I wish to understand "*subsistit in*" according to the Conciliar context.  Ideally this would be done through the official interventions of those present at the Council (the *Acta*).  Less ideally it could be done with documents which were not official interventions but yet were produced by those who were present at the Council.  *Dominus Iesu* isn't altogether irrelevant since a council theologian had a large hand in it (Ratzinger).  Nevertheless I don't believe it seeks to be an interpretation that limits itself to the Council context.